# how to pass null as value of a variable in data of ajax method

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I want to send a null value in the "mailID" field as email id is not a required field in the form.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.ButtonClick = function() {
        var post = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "url",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                name: $scope.Name,
                mailID: $scope.MailID,
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        post.success(function(data, status) {
            $window.alert(data.d);
        });
        post.error(function(data, status) {
            $window.alert(data.Message);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: use this `data: {
  name: $scope.Name,
  mailID: ($scope.MailID) ? $scope.MailID : null
 }`

Comment: Shows error-"Cannot convert null to a value type"

Comment: which line the error occur

Comment: post.error(function(data, status) {
            $window.alert(data.Message);
        });

Comment: that response comes from the serveside. you need to handle it from bac end

Comment: Is there any other way to pass a null value? plz help.

Comment: why do you need to pass null value. just pass empty string and handle it in  the srve

Comment: if I pass empty string its not hitting the web method so I am not able to debug.As it was not hitting the web method in backend I added "post.error(function(data, status) {
            $window.alert(data.Message);
        });" in the post method.

Comment: See the answer below, just don't send the `MailID` when not available. Your server has to handle the check though.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @sachila ranawaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `MailID` is not set, just don't send it along your `data` object.
Your server needs to check wheter the `MailID` is available or not.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.ButtonClick = function() {

        var data = {};
        data.name = $scope.Name;
        angular.isDefined($scope.MailID) data.MailID = $scope.MailID;

        var post = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "url",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        post.success(function(data, status) {
            $window.alert(data.d);
        });
        post.error(function(data, status) {
            $window.alert(data.Message);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Shows  the same error-"Cannot convert null to a value type"

Comment: Show error-"Invalid Web service call,Missing value for parameter:'mailID".So how to send the other values which are optional to the same method if I am not sending through data of post method.Can I use if else to call 2 differnt web method to filter parameters accordingly?

Comment: You have to encounter that the parameters can be optional... This is a server side change you will have to make. The above should answer your question regarding the request parameters. About the server side problems, please extend your original question or ask a new one.

Comment: if ($scope.MailID== null || $scope.MailID== '' || $scope.MailID== undefined) {
                    $scope.MailID= 'null';
                }

Comment: Added the above with your code and it worked thanks a ton.I am new to angular js but guided me with patience.Thanks

Comment: Please indicate the answer with the ^ and check it as answer in case it solved. Thanks